# Installing Ubuntu - Can't see my partitioned HDD

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, usb-installation

I try to install Ubuntu 16.04 with USB but i have a problem.

[image: screenshot]

I can't find my HDD. When i click Install Now, the installation process crash and restart my laptop.

In terminal when i type  *sudo fdisk -l*  i get this :

```
Disk /dev/ram0: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram1: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram2: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram3: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram4: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram5: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram6: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram7: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram8: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram9: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram10: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram11: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram12: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram13: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram14: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram15: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/loop0: 1.4 GiB, 1459982336 bytes, 2851528 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 28.9 GiB, 31004295168 bytes, 60555264 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x051be76c

Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *     2048 60555263 60553216 28.9G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

Here is my computer model:

```
 product: Inspiron N5010 (To be filled by O.E.M.)
   product: 0YXXJJ
      product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i3 CPU       M 380  @ 2.53GHz
         product: M471B5773DH0-CH9
         product: DBST4GN568S
      product: Core Processor DRAM Controller
         product: Core Processor PCI Express x16 Root Port
            product: Madison [Mobility Radeon HD 5650/5750 / 6530M/6550M]
            product: Redwood HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 5000 Series]
         product: 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset HECI Controller
         product: 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller
            product: EHCI Host Controller
               product: Integrated Rate Matching Hub
                  product: FLASH DRIVE
                  product: Laptop_Integrated_Webcam_1.3M
         product: 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio
         product: 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 1
         product: 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 2
            product: BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter
         product: 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 3
            product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
         product: 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 5
         product: 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller
            product: EHCI Host Controller
               product: Integrated Rate Matching Hub
                  product: BCM2046B1
                     product: Integrated Keyboard
                     product: Integrated Touchpad [Synaptics]
                     product: Dell Wireless 365 Bluetooth Module
         product: 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge
         product: HM57 Chipset LPC Interface Controller
         product: 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset 6 port SATA AHCI Controller
         product: 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset SMBus Controller
      product: Core Processor QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-core Registers
      product: Core Processor QuickPath Architecture System Address Decoder
      product: Core Processor QPI Link 0
      product: 1st Generation Core i3/5/7 Processor QPI Physical 0
      product: 1st Generation Core i3/5/7 Processor Reserved
      product: 1st Generation Core i3/5/7 Processor Reserved
         product: DVD+-RW TS-L633J
   product: DELL JXFRP0C
```

Right now I'm working on Try Ubuntu.

Have any idea how to install Ubuntu ?

Comment: Something is really wrong. Put up a screenshot of gparted view of your hard disk... if it sees it. Are we talking laptop or desktop? Any other OS installed? Please advise. Al

Comment: Laptop and i cant see gparted, In this moment i don't have any OS installed. previously Ubunut 16.04, something went wrong. I shut down and when i start i have Blackscreen and no OS. And now i tried to install ubuntu but this problem shown. 

and now just try Ubuntu works for me :/ :(

Answer (score 1):

Your disk is in hibernate mode, because windows 8/8.1/10  do that for accelerating the boot time.   "Suspend" and "Shutdown" do the same, so make sure if you want to boot a liveusb for linux just use the option "restart" and boot the pendrive.

If you dont believe me try to access the windows partition via nautilus(file manager) it will appear a error saying that you cant access the partition.

Comment: Even If the disk is still in hibernation, the disk should still be shown. It's just the partition that goes into hibernation, not entire disk